# Have any prominent politicians in the US called for US troops to leave Iraq this year?

Tags: united-states, military, iraq

Some US politicians, like DeSantis, have [said](https://floridapolitics.com/archives/642073-sitting-ducks/) US troops in Iraq are just "sitting ducks", at their present strength, so called for either a surge or departure.

> “We’ve got troops in Syria and Iraq. It’s not clear what their mission is. They’re there in insufficient numbers to probably make a huge impact, but they’re there in sufficient numbers to be an inviting target. And Iran has lobbed attacks on our troops,” DeSantis said.
>
> The “sitting ducks” line is a rehash from an interview a few days prior, where the Governor again suggested that while there may be too many or too few American assets deployed, it’s clear the current number simply isn’t right.

However, one [opinion](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/XwR6TLa4kiM) is that they "should go on the offensive" against Iran (after being reinforced). I'll ask about that later/separately. For now I want to know: **have any prominent US politician *unambiguously* asked for those troops to just be pulled out**, this year. Or is this option outside the Overton window among prominent US politicians?

---

To kind-of self-answer; I [see](https://www.defensenews.com/congress/2023/12/07/senate-votes-to-keep-us-troops-in-syria-amid-iran-backed-attacks/) there was a vote in the Senate in December to withdraw US troops from neighboring Syria. It was defeated 13-84. The only supporter mentioned there by name is Rand Paul, who advanced that bill. That article also mentions that earlier, in March 2023 the House voted on a similar resolution on Syria, introduced by Matt Gaetz; that one was rejected 103-321. I'm not sure if there has been anything similar (i.e. actual vote) regarding Iraq, recently--that would be a more definitive answer. (Iraqi PM al-Soudani has started to issue strong [calls](https://www.newarab.com/news/iraqi-pm-al-sudani-demands-us-troops-leave-country) for US forces to withdraw, in the past [couple of months](https://english.news.cn/20240221/3323aa6c0d44480fa7773b5d6897057a/c.html), at least.)

Comment: That sounds like DeSantis called for them to leave and he is pretty prominent.

Comment: @JoeW: actually he wasn't that explicit. He phrased it as an "either/or": reinforce or withdraw. I've added that para. I'm looking for some who are explicitly calling just for withdrawal.

Comment: Don't ask "whatabout" questions.  Such questions seem to invite debate, not answers.

Comment: @JamesK: [what](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6763/why-isnt-there-i-dont-like-this-question-closure-reason)?

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat: One problem with the "Whatabout" question here is that this question is decidedly different than the Russia invasion of Ukraine - the soldiers [still in Iraq are supporting the government in an intervention against ISIL as a coalition - and in particular, are kept past the combat mission to serve as trainers and advisors to Iraqi security forces.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US-led_intervention_in_Iraq_(2014%E2%80%932021)). Or to put another way, "To the extent that they are sitting ducks, it's because they are intentionally not engaging in combat.".

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st: looks like they're having 2nd thoughts about that. https://www.newarab.com/news/iraqi-pm-al-sudani-demands-us-troops-leave-country Iraqi Prime Minister Mohamed Shia al-Sudani: "The end of the international coalition mission is a necessity for the security and stability of Iraq". (Never realized he had "Shia" in his name until now, somehow.)

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st: And "He said that the IS group no longer poses a threat to Iraq's security, adding that the capabilities of the Iraqi security forces have improved significantly and it can now maintain security throughout the country." https://english.news.cn/20240221/3323aa6c0d44480fa7773b5d6897057a/c.html

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat: I won't argue that the Iraqi government is asking them to leave as they appear to be outstaying their welcome, but I will still hold that it doesn't appear that the U.S. troops are being offensive in nature, but in trying to simply be reactionary or supportive of local troops where possible.

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st: And that seems to be the problem, according to many in the GOP.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat: But are you asking for a "Complete retreat of all forces", or is the fact that most of the U.S. forces in Iraq have essentially retreated as meeting that requirement? They've appeared to have done the latter, relegating their troops to advisory roles.

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st: you're grasping at straws.

Comment: The pattern I dislike is where there some countries that are geopolitical opponents X, and Y. Person A asks a rather "pushy" question about country X, then person B) perhaps trying to establish "balance" asks a similar question about country Y.  "What about the actions of country Y, these are worse than country X"" implying that criticism of country X by Y is unjustified.  My problem is that the second question isn't really a question, but an attempt to debate the framing of the first question.  These often aren't helpful and only attract partisans, and sarcastic answers.

Comment: @JamesK: this was not meant as any kind of "equalizer". (I don't even get the logic of how a Q about US forces in Iraq "equalizes" a Q about supporting Russia-Ukraine negotiations.) If you dislike this type of Q "who [else] has this position", there's alas a ton of those here.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, Matt Gaetz at least [made](https://www.newsweek.com/matt-gaetz-calls-us-withdrawal-iraq-after-drone-attack-1855641) an unambiguous statement (unless context was omitted) to withdraw US troops from Iraq too, in December:

> "We should leave Iraq," Gaetz, a conservative, wrote in a post to his personal account on X, formerly Twitter, Tuesday afternoon.

I found the [actual tweet](https://twitter.com/mattgaetz/status/1739724125135065352) (dated Dec 26) but that's all it says. It was though in response to another tweet about recent US wounded there.

Comment: One might think Rand Paul would also supports this [quick withdrawal from Iraq], but I'm 100% on that and I wasn't able to find a recent/clear statement. About 10 years ago he [did](https://www.fff.org/2014/11/24/rand-paul-wrong-leave-iraq-alone/) support the intervention against ISIS (but not the 2003 invasion). So, I suppose it's a matter of risk/reward for him.